# Send Email through Proxy Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, proxy, laravel-8

I am trying to send an email to a guest in laravel.
Below is my code:

```
Mail::to($requestor->email)->send(new ApprovedNotification(auth()->user()->name));
```

The question is how can I send the email through proxy? Does it requires any server side configuration or I can just set it in laravel? The code is running fine when I am using my home network but when using my company server, the SMTP can't be sent out. ( The weird thing is the Jetstream team invitation email can be sent, but the customized emails cant)

Below is my email configuration:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: you must generate app password if you are using gmail

Comment: I didnt receive any error, but the server never respond back to me @John Lobo

Comment: okay.are you using app password ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gmail then you must generate App password.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833/sign-in-with-app-passwords?hl=en

then your mail configuration look like this

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```